# error generating java header file

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to create a java header file. I compiled the project in netbeans then in command line i type the following:

```
javah -classpath C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JNITest\build\classes.jnitest HelloWorld
```

I also tried:

```
javah -classpath C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JNITest\build\classes\jnitest HelloWorld
```

But I am getting an error: Could not find clas file for `HelloWorld` .

The class is clearly there located in:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JNITest\build\classes\jnitest\HelloWorld.class
```

How should I correctly specify the path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
javah -classpath C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JNITest\build\classes jnitest.HelloWorld
                 ^---------------- class folder ------------------------------^ ^--- classname --^
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoi,

Oracle has a good tutorial about this:
[Javah - Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javah.html)

The catch is to specify the **full qualified class name** correctly. I guess you have set a package for your `HelloWorld` class, so that package must be within the path too.